# How to merge two files line by line in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have two text files, each of them contains an information by line such like that

```
file1.txt            file2.txt
----------           ---------
linef11              linef21
linef12              linef22
linef13              linef23
 .                    .
 .                    .
 .                    .
```

I would like to merge theses files lines by lines using a bash script in order to obtain:

```
fileresult.txt
--------------
linef11     linef21
linef12     linef22
linef13     linef23
 .           .
 .           .
 .           .
```

How can this be done in Bash?

Answer (score 349, accepted):

You can use [`paste`](http://ss64.com/bash/paste.html):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt > fileresults.txt
```

Comment: How does it work if I would like to use a delimiter?

Comment: @SOaddict ```paste -d "\n" * > results.txt```

Comment: `paste` will separate each column with a tab unless you override with the `-d` option, so you can use something like `awk`, `sed`, etc... to format each line.  Example: `paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{printf "%-61s | %s\n", $1,$2}'` ... this mimics the `diff --side-by-side` output)

Comment: `paste -d ""` to concatenate lines without delimeters, space

Answer (score 25):

here's non-paste methods

awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=" "}{
  getline line < "file2"
  print $0,line
} ' file1
```

Bash

```
exec 6<"file2"
while read -r line
do
    read -r f2line <&6
    echo "${line}${f2line}"
done <"file1"
exec 6<&-
```

Answer (score 15):

Try following.

```
pr -tmJ a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

Comment: Also, use the -s option if you want to change the separator. (+1)

Comment: the J option does not work on macOS Mojave but your command does perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Check

```
man paste
```

possible followed by some command like `untabify` or `tabs2spaces`

Comment: M-x replace-string in Emacs will take out tabs, presumably Vim and maybe some other text editors can do it too.

Comment: use the -d option to specify a separator other than tab

Answer (score 6):

You can use paste with the delimiter option if you want to merge and separate two texts in the file

```
paste -d "," source_file1 source_file2 > destination_file
```

Without specifying the delimiter will merge two text files using a Tab delimiter

```
paste source_file1 source_file2 > destination_file
```