# combine one colum from two files into a thrid file

Tags: sed, awk

I have two files a.txt and b.txt which contains the following data.

```
$ cat a.txt
0x5212cb03caa111e0
0x5212cb03caa113c0
0x5212cb03caa115c0
0x5212cb03caa117c0
0x5212cb03caa119e0
0x5212cb03caa11bc0
0x5212cb03caa11dc0
0x5212cb03caa11fc0
0x5212cb03caa121c0

$ cat b.txt
36 65 fb 60 7a 5e
36 65 fb 60 7a 64
36 65 fb 60 7a 6a
36 65 fb 60 7a 70
36 65 fb 60 7a 76
36 65 fb 60 7a 7c
36 65 fb 60 7a 82
36 65 fb 60 7a 88
36 65 fb 60 7a 8e
```

I want to generate a third file c.txt that contains

```
0x5212cb03caa111e0      36 65 fb 60 7a 5e
0x5212cb03caa113c0      36 65 fb 60 7a 64 
0x5212cb03caa115c0      36 65 fb 60 7a 6a
```

Can I achieve this using awk? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste is really the shortest solution, however if you're looking for awk solution as stated in question then:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] "\t" $0}' a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

use `paste` command:

```
paste a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk solution that only stores two lines in memory at a time:

```
awk '{ getline b < "b.txt"; print $0, b }' OFS='\t' a.txt
```

Lines from `a.txt` are implicitly stored in `$0` and for each line in `a.txt` a line is read from `b.txt` by `getline`.