# Ubuntu Terminal - Concatenate by columns

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 100 csv files with 1 cols with 100 rows fixed. I give example
ex: 1.csv 
11.012
21.012
01.012
29.012

ex: 2.csv 
1001.012
2100.012
-1.01200
-29.23012

I wish to concatenate all files into 1 where final look like
ex: log.csv
11.012 1001.012
21.012 2100.012
01.012 -1.01200
29.012 -29.23012

I try to use `cat` but it ended up with one huge row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two files line by line using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with cat just fine:

> cat file1 >> file2

The only reason why the above would not work as expected would be if you are using a specific delimiter.

You can do this in a loop. If you put all the files in a folder, you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash for f in $( ls ); do cat $f >> destinationfile done
```

There are numerous ways to do this of course, [you can check this for alternatives.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash)