# How to merge two files without matching rows

Tags: join, merge

I want to combine two files that are very different without any row matching:

File 1 (1000+ rows):

`M03558  203 5   23464   CTTGTA
M03559  205 3   1096    CTTGTQ
M03560  209 12  1956    CTTGTW
M035561 304 5   2347    CTTGTK
...`

File 2 (a table of 3 rows):

`A   12  34  78  0.3
B   13  35  79  0.3
C   14  36  80  0.5`

Desired outcome: 

`M03558  203 5   23464   CTTGTA      A   12  34  78  0.3
M03559  205 3   1096    CTTGTQ      B   13  35  79  0.3
M03560  209 12  1956    CTTGTW      C   14  36  80  0.5
M03561  304 5   2347    CTTGTK

...`

Is there any way to achieve that in bash, perl, python or R, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two files line by line using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash)

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can use the `paste` command:

```
paste -d " " file1 file2 > outfile
```

If, instead of a space seperating the two merged records, you wanted a tab character then:

```
paste -d "\t" file1 file2 > outfile
```

Comment: This is a poor quality question that shows no research effort, and is clearly a duplicate. Questions like these shouldn't be answered.