# Merging multiple CSV files by column

Tags: csv

How would I go about merging multiple CSV files into one by column. What I have recorded are chart positions of, say, companies scraped from a webpage. Only the first file has two columns, for positions 1 to 100, and a second column containing the companies' name. All other files only have one column; conaining the company name only. Now I want to merge these as described below. Mac/Linux solutions preferred. I can write Bash, a little JavaScript but Perl is not my forte.

`1.csv`:

```
position,name
1,microsoft
2,apple
3,google
```

And various other files, named after their date, looking like this:

`2.csv`:

```
name
microsoft
apple
google
```

`3.csv`:

```
name
apple
microsoft
google
```

The merged version would look like this:

```
position,name,name,name
1,microsoft,microsoft,apple
2,apple,apple,microsoft
3,google,google,google
```

The only solutions I could find, simply add (or concatenate) the content after another, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two files line by line using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash) how is this not what you're looking for? the end result is exactly what you're looking for?! param `-d ","` of course (https://ss64.com/bash/paste.html)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really indicated which language you'd prefer to work in. But if you would like to work in python, you can download pandas and load your csv into a pandas table. You could then use a table join to achieve what you're asking :)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  If `filter.jq` contains the following filter:

```
def parse:
  reduce ( inputs
         | {f:input_filename, r:split(",")}
         | select(.r|length>0)
  ) as $i (
    {}
  ; .[$i.f] += [$i.r]
  )
;

def reorg:
    range([ map_values(length)[] ] | max) as $r
  | [ .[] | .[$r] // [range(.[0]|length)|""] | .[] ]
;

parse | reorg | join(",")
```

and the files `1.csv`, `2.csv` and `3.csv` contain the sample data then the command

```
$ jq -Rrn -f filter.jq 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv
```

produces

```
position,name,name,name
1,microsoft,microsoft,apple
2,apple,apple,microsoft
3,google,google,google
```