# Merging lines with certain lines in bash

Tags: bash, parsing

i was parsing some data in bash and I could not firure out how to do it. I need to merge the lines together, so it looks like this:

```
70:54:D2:8D:82:9A 1 Internet
...
```

I have these 3 file outputs.

Mac addresses:

```
70:54:D2:8D:82:9A
F8:8E:85:84:4F:55
F4:6D:04:B0:C2:18
10:FE:ED:78:2A:44
```

Channel numbers:

```
1
4
1
8
```

and SSIDs:

```
Internet
ASUS
Free-WiFi
NetFree
```

Is there a simple way of doing so? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems like someone already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash)

Comment: What is the basis for merging?  Do you have a common column in all three files? If so, you can try the `join` command.  `paste` will do but a simple merge may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-bash

Comment: `paste` is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command to append the lines of the files together...

`paste -d " " macs channels SSIds`

Here's a full example...

```
echo "123" > 1
echo "abc" > 2
echo "@#$" > 3
paste -d " " 1 2 3

123 abc @#$

echo "456" >> 1
paste -d " " 1 2 3

123 abc @#$
456
```

So you can see that if the line counts don't match up you'll get some slightly skewed output so you'll want to make sure the lines are 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ]$ paste 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
  70:54:D2:8D:82:9A 1   Internet
  F8:8E:85:84:4F:55 4   ASUS
  F4:6D:04:B0:C2:18 1   Free-WiFi
  10:FE:ED:78:2A:44 8   NetFree
```