# Loading pretrained Word2vec model

Tags: python, r, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have some pretrained Word2vec models that I need to load both in Python and R. They are in txt.gz extension. I extracted them by 7-zip and could get the txt files. I use the following code to load them in Python:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('syn0_ngram_1900_1909_full.txt', binary = False)
```

However, I get these errors:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-31e3fee59511>", line 1, in <module>
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('syn0_ngram_1900_1909_full.txt' , binary = False)

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1547, in load_word2vec_format
    return _load_word2vec_format(

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py", line 277, in _load_word2vec_format
    vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py", line 277, in <genexpr>
    vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.552761644124984741e-01'
```

The first 3 lines of the file look like this:

```
-1.552761644124984741e-01 -4.447535425424575806e-02 2.490501850843429565e-01 6.936315447092056274e-02 4.821906611323356628e-02 1.374670863151550293e-01 -3.902152925729751587e-02 -9.022397547960281372e-02 -2.184277474880218506e-01 2.209668904542922974e-01 -3.469136059284210205e-01 -1.411392092704772949e-01 -4.453907907009124756e-01 -1.025922745466232300e-01 8.120749890804290771e-02 -4.073899090290069580e-01 -1.905823498964309692e-02 -8.645015209913253784e-02 -7.905063778162002563e-02 7.617127150297164917e-02 1.504308432340621948e-01 8.758410811424255371e-03 3.396979570388793945e-01 -2.586390674114227295e-01 2.386739850044250488e-01 1.265343427658081055e-01 2.472167760133743286e-01 3.401717543601989746e-02 6.056435406208038330e-02 1.221914887428283691e-01 -8.905990421772003174e-02 -9.887123107910156250e-02 -9.832112491130828857e-02 -7.572189718484878540e-02 -7.369377184659242630e-03 1.302516758441925049e-01 -1.231815069913864136e-01 2.606352046132087708e-02 1.441473066806793213e-01 -1.717498451471328735e-01 9.777273982763290405e-03 6.302291993051767349e-03 8.990994654595851898e-03 -1.062645390629768372e-01 1.878743618726730347e-01 5.820669233798980713e-02 -1.301994770765304565e-01 1.007045060396194458e-01 -8.061264455318450928e-02 -1.923392526805400848e-02 9.648428112268447876e-02 -2.001685947179794312e-01 -1.039923876523971558e-01 1.369088292121887207e-01 3.344058617949485779e-02 -8.220246434211730957e-02 2.154016494750976562e-01 -1.533902585506439209e-01 -9.639452397823333740e-02 -1.077244579792022705e-01 3.839006647467613220e-02 -9.669522196054458618e-02 1.057831645011901855e-01 -1.731183379888534546e-01 -1.823752373456954956e-01 1.329025924205780029e-01 1.256246417760848999e-01 -5.657993257045745850e-02 -2.921316400170326233e-02 -6.282752007246017456e-02 1.006662324070930481e-01 6.356491148471832275e-02 1.589829623699188232e-01 1.770073324441909790e-01 4.362170770764350891e-02 -1.918367296457290649e-01 -3.448316827416419983e-02 -5.027920752763748169e-02 9.733915328979492188e-02 3.966502845287322998e-01 3.811245039105415344e-02 -2.094386219978332520e-01 3.425932824611663818e-01 -2.924242429435253143e-02 2.225339598953723907e-02 2.787167727947235107e-01 1.680488288402557373e-01 7.655870169401168823e-02 3.952257335186004639e-02 -2.619512081146240234e-01 -3.033895492553710938e-01 -5.149876475334167480e-01 -1.642060428857803345e-01 -1.959302574396133423e-01 1.126131117343902588e-01 -2.267295867204666138e-01 2.400911971926689148e-02 4.052775725722312927e-02 -3.044707141816616058e-02 -3.633485138416290283e-01 -2.818429283797740936e-02 -4.622202217578887939e-01 9.291686117649078369e-02 -2.956802845001220703e-01 1.862034201622009277e-01 1.242911815643310547e-01 1.026049628853797913e-01 1.160985007882118225e-01 -1.380904614925384521e-01 1.792961508035659790e-01 1.492877304553985596e-01 2.356165647506713867e-01 -2.932927012443542480e-02 1.063521653413772583e-01 3.353847563266754150e-01 1.908604428172111511e-02 3.782559633255004883e-01 -1.517397463321685791e-01 3.612821102142333984e-01 1.607065051794052124e-01 9.656509757041931152e-02 1.245319694280624390e-01 1.315144896507263184e-01 7.511320710182189941e-02 -4.755245521664619446e-02 -2.734144330024719238e-01 3.033797740936279297e-01 5.215175449848175049e-03 2.141999304294586182e-01 -1.597059220075607300e-01 3.182544559240341187e-02 4.125118851661682129e-01 -2.834559679031372070e-01 2.971411049365997314e-01 2.584041953086853027e-01 2.266484946012496948e-01 1.358106434345245361e-01 -8.042504638433456421e-02 -2.925538420677185059e-01 6.947112828493118286e-02 3.138780593872070312e-01 -1.517586410045623779e-01 -2.561317682266235352e-01 -1.843494027853012085e-01 2.936672978103160858e-02 -1.237718015909194946e-01 6.020113825798034668e-02 5.157970264554023743e-02 1.483027786016464233e-01 1.515904515981674194e-01 -7.338423281908035278e-02 1.898889243602752686e-02 2.750496566295623779e-02 -6.313492357730865479e-02 -2.602603659033775330e-02 -4.748337436467409134e-03 3.420833945274353027e-01 -5.720657855272293091e-02 -2.232243567705154419e-01 4.226108267903327942e-02 6.031884625554084778e-02 1.539045125246047974e-01 8.576720207929611206e-02 1.011675968766212463e-01 -3.795365989208221436e-01 -3.146133571863174438e-02 1.349445134401321411e-01 2.983746826648712158e-01 -2.938828170299530029e-01 1.533054113388061523e-01 -4.229364991188049316e-01 9.155936539173126221e-02 -2.974963048473000526e-03 -1.385585069656372070e-01 -1.053368579596281052e-02 1.153212636709213257e-01 3.379225432872772217e-01 -9.703439474105834961e-02 -1.578260511159896851e-01 -6.252604722976684570e-02 1.598290950059890747e-01 2.294627018272876740e-03 6.054456159472465515e-02 1.103171482682228088e-01 1.407995820045471191e-02 1.977602243423461914e-01 -7.971014082431793213e-02 6.747842580080032349e-02 -7.176994532346725464e-02 3.453086316585540771e-02 1.144322603940963745e-01 -1.870087534189224243e-01 -1.876662820577621460e-01 6.476462818682193756e-03 -8.064353466033935547e-02 -1.166440173983573914e-01 -3.607030212879180908e-02 -2.510503865778446198e-02 6.253489851951599121e-02 1.802610009908676147e-01 4.245756864547729492e-01 -1.071699485182762146e-01 -1.976074464619159698e-02 7.162892073392868042e-02 -2.126150727272033691e-01 -1.831589490175247192e-01 -7.786697894334793091e-02 1.421018242835998535e-01 2.083165943622589111e-01 -9.992305934429168701e-02 7.392542809247970581e-02 9.227126836776733398e-02 -1.524462252855300903e-01 2.111838459968566895e-01 1.633472144603729248e-01 6.497748196125030518e-02 6.825347244739532471e-02 -3.643653988838195801e-01 1.698636859655380249e-01 6.742136925458908081e-02 2.124408334493637085e-01 -2.609764039516448975e-01 -4.775075241923332214e-02 -1.276874262839555740e-02 -9.566855616867542267e-03 -7.416314631700515747e-02 -1.711301803588867188e-01 2.018006443977355957e-01 -4.967777058482170105e-03 7.954392582178115845e-02 -8.138674497604370117e-02 2.610500156879425049e-01 3.377711772918701172e-02 -2.635057568550109863e-01 7.423927634954452515e-02 -2.577809691429138184e-01 -7.702536880970001221e-02 1.627112627029418945e-01 1.897031962871551514e-01 -1.299263685941696167e-01 1.664789579808712006e-02 -6.737360358238220215e-02 -2.183234542608261108e-01 2.616149485111236572e-01 -1.861911714076995850e-01 -8.766605705022811890e-02 5.951049551367759705e-02 3.398019671440124512e-01 1.241989135742187500e-01 1.123771518468856812e-01 2.735071256756782532e-02 7.581159472465515137e-03 -1.705877929925918579e-01 9.298118948936462402e-02 -5.501312017440795898e-02 2.464835159480571747e-02 1.904888302087783813e-01 1.251959949731826782e-01 -9.753731638193130493e-02 4.099815338850021362e-02 -3.088685572147369385e-01 4.752117022871971130e-02 -1.016708761453628540e-01 2.049167454242706299e-01 -1.110423356294631958e-01 -2.558538317680358887e-02 9.703662991523742676e-02 1.440881937742233276e-01 -1.499230116605758667e-01 4.630966186523437500e-01 1.560464948415756226e-01 -2.473618537187576294e-01 7.339747250080108643e-02 -1.125243376009166241e-03 2.308040857315063477e-03 -7.349326461553573608e-02 -5.643999949097633362e-02 -1.791801899671554565e-01 3.374390304088592529e-02 5.359465628862380981e-02 4.016261696815490723e-01 -8.631563186645507812e-02 -1.041909903287887573e-01 -9.027398191392421722e-03 7.635752111673355103e-02 -1.177581623196601868e-01 6.990105658769607544e-02 -1.495847105979919434e-01 -1.948498487472534180e-01 -1.003706827759742737e-01 2.158978767693042755e-02 2.253228724002838135e-01 -8.305017650127410889e-02 9.877178817987442017e-02 -1.782058775424957275e-01 -4.364309012889862061e-01 2.809965051710605621e-02 5.815667286515235901e-02 9.305762499570846558e-02 9.939935058355331421e-02
-2.755518853664398193e-01 7.426643371582031250e-02 1.305104941129684448e-01 1.733209006488323212e-02 3.392809331417083740e-01 4.914091154932975769e-02 -5.487316101789474487e-02 -2.893702983856201172e-01 -3.995743691921234131e-01 1.019903868436813354e-01 -5.586374923586845398e-02 -2.909922003746032715e-01 -1.379316449165344238e-01 -1.213544141501188278e-02 -2.101085036993026733e-01 -4.060855805873870850e-01 2.363941520452499390e-01 -1.304764747619628906e-01 -1.898821741342544556e-01 7.960485666990280151e-02 6.144599989056587219e-02 -8.303866721689701080e-03 1.456501632928848267e-01 -1.511054039001464844e-01 3.446572422981262207e-01 1.809655129909515381e-01 3.376641869544982910e-01 -1.289701908826828003e-01 1.942324079573154449e-02 1.295022666454315186e-01 1.819744110107421875e-01 9.251490980386734009e-02 1.657947003841400146e-01 -4.376604557037353516e-01 2.938240170478820801e-01 -1.873110830783843994e-01 -1.355587989091873169e-01 -2.293781042098999023e-01 -9.990473277866840363e-03 -1.429447233676910400e-01 4.837138950824737549e-02 4.135683923959732056e-02 1.273282319307327271e-01 -1.000547260046005249e-01 3.860374540090560913e-02 3.943286091089248657e-02 7.455765455961227417e-02 -1.942279636859893799e-01 1.055958718061447144e-01 -1.248219236731529236e-01 6.977072358131408691e-02 8.551878482103347778e-02 4.604674875736236572e-02 -1.508192718029022217e-01 -2.823450267314910889e-01 -1.705607175827026367e-01 1.018783375620841980e-01 9.879937022924423218e-02 -4.601259529590606689e-02 -1.719024218618869781e-02 -1.294963657855987549e-01 -5.334546416997909546e-02 1.102923452854156494e-01 3.475880622863769531e-02 3.030833788216114044e-02 3.598376810550689697e-01 1.075935140252113342e-01 1.747883707284927368e-01 2.600349187850952148e-01 -4.294164106249809265e-02 3.064307570457458496e-01 3.595127537846565247e-02 8.350577205419540405e-02 4.761104285717010498e-02 1.397927701473236084e-01 6.383475847542285919e-03 -1.242930628359317780e-02 -6.513260304927825928e-02 -1.765230298042297363e-01 2.290750741958618164e-01 1.070840135216712952e-01 -1.611845940351486206e-01 2.256397455930709839e-01 3.962266817688941956e-02 -1.251329332590103149e-01 -8.839791268110275269e-02 -8.401984721422195435e-02 -1.068911850452423096e-01 4.183220565319061279e-01 -1.719796285033226013e-02 -1.992868930101394653e-01 -1.439917534589767456e-01 -3.158213943243026733e-02 1.782516241073608398e-01 -2.040623277425765991e-01 -2.465122565627098083e-02 3.390240948647260666e-03 -2.063101902604103088e-02 3.736664727330207825e-02 -1.950853466987609863e-01 7.347257435321807861e-02 -3.684818744659423828e-01 -3.807673603296279907e-02 -6.298073381185531616e-02 3.570814132690429688e-01 1.056838855147361755e-01 -6.606206297874450684e-02 1.103219836950302124e-01 1.340708583593368530e-01 1.316183954477310181e-01 1.801468431949615479e-01 2.364787608385086060e-01 -2.933555981144309044e-03 1.394167244434356689e-01 1.410789489746093750e-01 2.110916227102279663e-01 -3.954877331852912903e-02 -1.672693789005279541e-01 4.702991843223571777e-01 6.913857907056808472e-02 1.212535426020622253e-01 -8.544678986072540283e-02 1.632798463106155396e-01 -9.701278060674667358e-02 6.379171460866928101e-02 3.686433658003807068e-03 2.002136409282684326e-02 -2.272810041904449463e-01 2.025170065462589264e-02 -2.601526863873004913e-02 -2.050084173679351807e-01 1.567473113536834717e-01 9.391159564256668091e-02 -8.464719355106353760e-02 1.202475205063819885e-01 2.147839069366455078e-01 3.591004014015197754e-01 -1.711977422237396240e-01 -2.318718731403350830e-01 1.340079754590988159e-01 -3.448984399437904358e-02 2.319254539906978607e-02 -2.770109176635742188e-01 -3.476117849349975586e-01 -2.453668564558029175e-01 1.853164657950401306e-02 6.908061355352401733e-02 -8.381587266921997070e-02 -9.367397427558898926e-02 2.148762494325637817e-01 1.584969758987426758e-01 3.585815057158470154e-02 -2.491751015186309814e-01 -1.422119513154029846e-02 7.534956187009811401e-02 1.988542675971984863e-01 9.783649444580078125e-02 -1.565352529287338257e-01 -1.734849214553833008e-01 -6.991375982761383057e-02 3.639198243618011475e-01 1.621825546026229858e-01 -6.586146354675292969e-02 5.274389684200286865e-02 1.484267711639404297e-01 1.349460333585739136e-01 -1.060503944754600525e-01 2.191036790609359741e-01 4.246726259589195251e-02 -1.529514938592910767e-01 5.295782908797264099e-02 7.367381453514099121e-02 3.147679939866065979e-02 -1.366107761859893799e-01 -6.432162970304489136e-02 2.987476065754890442e-02 9.375686198472976685e-02 -3.127529919147491455e-01 -1.916600018739700317e-02 -1.505621522665023804e-01 -2.707700803875923157e-02 -3.426384180784225464e-03 -5.949690937995910645e-02 8.628486841917037964e-02 -1.401778589934110641e-02 2.023975551128387451e-01 -1.908088102936744690e-02 -2.119334191083908081e-01 1.441151797771453857e-01 1.514745354652404785e-01 -7.387769222259521484e-02 -1.496255546808242798e-01 -4.099091142416000366e-02 3.930757343769073486e-01 -1.470357030630111694e-01 -2.854492068290710449e-01 3.818158432841300964e-02 1.000983938574790955e-01 2.482949197292327881e-01 -1.042249724268913269e-01 1.192888319492340088e-01 -5.882263556122779846e-02 -1.760703176259994507e-01 1.793773612007498741e-03 -8.517112582921981812e-02 -8.584306389093399048e-02 -9.191264398396015167e-03 1.277624070644378662e-01 1.232503578066825867e-01 -5.207545310258865356e-02 -1.516743302345275879e-01 8.217832446098327637e-02 1.153566017746925354e-01 4.729519486427307129e-01 5.880970880389213562e-02 1.440012007951736450e-01 -2.476142048835754395e-01 -2.377158254384994507e-01 1.911669075489044189e-01 3.252712637186050415e-02 1.070735454559326172e-01 -6.179307028651237488e-02 -2.360517531633377075e-01 -2.577443122863769531e-01 -5.894837155938148499e-02 3.033825755119323730e-01 -3.594714030623435974e-02 3.514684969559311867e-03 -4.581563547253608704e-02 -1.858881562948226929e-01 1.027334555983543396e-01 2.197035700082778931e-01 2.374446019530296326e-02 -1.158262640237808228e-01 1.136242374777793884e-01 -2.748361043632030487e-02 4.605894163250923157e-02 -7.746911793947219849e-02 1.829507201910018921e-01 -6.030893698334693909e-02 -2.890438400208950043e-02 1.853499114513397217e-01 -2.043003737926483154e-01 3.536553680896759033e-02 -8.747279644012451172e-02 3.783982396125793457e-01 2.096020579338073730e-01 1.197393238544464111e-01 2.897605299949645996e-01 -1.817464530467987061e-01 -1.201971098780632019e-01 5.573973059654235840e-03 -3.500255197286605835e-02 -7.611036300659179688e-02 -2.485055625438690186e-01 6.760949641466140747e-02 -7.421203702688217163e-02 2.240369617938995361e-01 2.368878340348601341e-03 -1.559459716081619263e-01 -3.354331552982330322e-01 -1.983614265918731689e-01 -1.804647594690322876e-01 -1.304219365119934082e-01 -2.911436557769775391e-02 1.543108224868774414e-01 -1.778330653905868530e-01 3.935296833515167236e-01 -8.174671977758407593e-02 2.501682937145233154e-01 -7.979557663202285767e-02 6.083849817514419556e-02 8.713995665311813354e-02 4.636264592409133911e-02 8.727990835905075073e-02 -1.660248637199401855e-01 1.531319767236709595e-01 -6.790683255530893803e-04 7.505177706480026245e-02 -1.619962751865386963e-01 1.066124737262725830e-01 -3.226042985916137695e-01 2.093208255246281624e-03 1.322522610425949097e-01 -2.231481522321701050e-01 1.296667754650115967e-01 -1.306195557117462158e-02 -1.684510260820388794e-01 1.680857092142105103e-01 -5.792901664972305298e-02 1.396010369062423706e-01 1.932041347026824951e-01 3.012113086879253387e-02 2.267901003360748291e-01 -3.265710771083831787e-01 -3.679866790771484375e-01 -2.241524606943130493e-01 -9.129060804843902588e-02 -1.781184524297714233e-01 2.713193893432617188e-01
-2.774842977523803711e-01 -2.998521625995635986e-01 -7.971244305372238159e-02 8.230878040194511414e-03 -1.816957741975784302e-01 3.503366410732269287e-01 3.937914967536926270e-01 3.818871676921844482e-01 -9.332147240638732910e-02 -1.803085207939147949e-02 -2.010484933853149414e-01 1.534142941236495972e-01 -1.827129423618316650e-01 2.424736320972442627e-01 -2.587919868528842926e-02 -1.459656208753585815e-01 -2.334953695535659790e-01 -2.997140884399414062e-01 -1.362463384866714478e-01 8.161799609661102295e-02 1.432602256536483765e-01 1.230252087116241455e-01 -1.510256156325340271e-02 6.471955031156539917e-02 1.789489835500717163e-01 2.171420454978942871e-01 4.145196378231048584e-01 1.729734390974044800e-01 1.356951594352722168e-01 2.059405446052551270e-01 1.503511667251586914e-01 -2.932371757924556732e-02 8.221655152738094330e-03 -2.987872958183288574e-01 -1.650227159261703491e-01 1.787729188799858093e-02 -1.364763826131820679e-01 -5.834015086293220520e-02 2.543235421180725098e-01 -1.790037006139755249e-01 -1.532125100493431091e-02 5.038385838270187378e-02 9.709338843822479248e-02 -2.102746218442916870e-01 1.455358881503343582e-02 -3.748860061168670654e-01 -7.003118097782135010e-02 4.741380214691162109e-01 4.043326899409294128e-02 -4.256066307425498962e-02 3.166067302227020264e-01 -7.988628745079040527e-02 -3.403761088848114014e-01 -7.842956483364105225e-02 -3.211471065878868103e-02 -8.283370733261108398e-02 1.359094232320785522e-01 1.110327914357185364e-01 6.995534151792526245e-02 -1.054197996854782104e-01 5.218173563480377197e-02 -1.197223141789436340e-01 4.968923330307006836e-02 -1.623026579618453979e-01 -3.258561789989471436e-01 2.500229775905609131e-01 3.593124151229858398e-01 -3.386449441313743591e-02 8.114624768495559692e-03 1.578128151595592499e-02 3.713388741016387939e-01 3.886390849947929382e-02 7.361979037523269653e-02 4.777812063694000244e-01 -3.187358081340789795e-01 -1.472535170614719391e-02 -1.864034235477447510e-01 2.851904034614562988e-01 2.424101158976554871e-02 3.765774965286254883e-01 4.411956071853637695e-01 1.843919754028320312e-01 6.076631136238574982e-03 1.195349693298339844e-01 -4.604819789528846741e-02 3.925660848617553711e-01 -1.517851352691650391e-01 -1.246303766965866089e-01 1.766519099473953247e-01 -1.822839528322219849e-01 -4.482288956642150879e-01 -3.685613870620727539e-01 -2.097260802984237671e-01 1.643853932619094849e-01 -4.741436839103698730e-01 1.948721590451896191e-03 -9.952253662049770355e-03 -1.998928934335708618e-01 -2.408249676227569580e-01 -1.873278170824050903e-01 1.068998277187347412e-01 1.051706746220588684e-01 2.129557281732559204e-01 2.287544757127761841e-01 9.127160906791687012e-02 5.938585847616195679e-02 2.965441048145294189e-01 2.421934902667999268e-01 -8.174385130405426025e-02 2.093371152877807617e-01 1.487546563148498535e-01 2.000252306461334229e-01 -6.509444862604141235e-02 -7.295352220535278320e-02 3.018093109130859375e-01 2.694353833794593811e-02 3.530837222933769226e-02 -5.731752514839172363e-02 1.747614592313766479e-01 1.560003608465194702e-01 2.684080004692077637e-01 1.080089155584573746e-02 1.087081581354141235e-01 1.963618397712707520e-02 4.157029837369918823e-02 -1.816155910491943359e-01 2.548927962779998779e-01 4.838272556662559509e-02 -1.472955197095870972e-01 -1.429838240146636963e-01 -1.541285365819931030e-01 2.681677043437957764e-01 -4.319681525230407715e-01 1.616368293762207031e-01 -8.768530935049057007e-02 -1.047493219375610352e-01 -1.213742494583129883e-01 1.956912130117416382e-02 1.767091825604438782e-02 3.966970741748809814e-01 3.049480617046356201e-01 -3.431919217109680176e-01 -2.700016498565673828e-01 1.273563951253890991e-01 -7.174579054117202759e-02 1.201752051711082458e-01 -2.558999061584472656e-01 2.808746397495269775e-01 -1.585903167724609375e-01 3.504217267036437988e-01 1.641803234815597534e-01 -7.637239992618560791e-02 1.117228902876377106e-02 -1.290193665772676468e-02 5.763415247201919556e-02 2.977091446518898010e-02 1.087564900517463684e-01 5.177070945501327515e-02 1.507237739861011505e-02 1.421540975570678711e-02 -2.560492157936096191e-01 7.064723372459411621e-01 -3.870822861790657043e-02 -9.608229249715805054e-02 -4.009970650076866150e-02 2.679672539234161377e-01 -6.665153801441192627e-02 3.355098664760589600e-01 2.569686770439147949e-01 -2.018120288848876953e-01 -1.346995588392019272e-02 -5.782928317785263062e-02 8.600515872240066528e-02 3.889953345060348511e-02 2.605972588062286377e-01 -6.099622845649719238e-01 3.195210993289947510e-01 -2.089240849018096924e-01 1.928902976214885712e-02 -4.566932469606399536e-02 -1.053371950984001160e-01 -3.651003818958997726e-03 -5.018276348710060120e-02 -9.367980808019638062e-02 -3.558373451232910156e-02 -4.714028537273406982e-02 -1.415439844131469727e-01 1.963711977005004883e-01 2.375491559505462646e-01 -6.988362222909927368e-02 -1.764807403087615967e-01 -2.329608052968978882e-01 -2.117581516504287720e-01 1.594799607992172241e-01 -1.619364023208618164e-01 -2.535828948020935059e-01 -3.168850392103195190e-02 -1.248130872845649719e-01 -3.917082026600837708e-02 -1.555472612380981445e-02 1.310855150222778320e-01 -1.109836474061012268e-01 1.193420886993408203e-01 -7.499247789382934570e-02 2.165957689285278320e-01 2.515639737248420715e-02 -7.427005469799041748e-02 3.367302119731903076e-01 1.033056080341339111e-01 -2.416009753942489624e-01 1.372187584638595581e-01 1.164045780897140503e-01 -2.295079827308654785e-01 2.349957227706909180e-01 -1.768460124731063843e-01 2.567556798458099365e-01 -1.244153752923011780e-01 -1.948076933622360229e-01 2.246239781379699707e-01 2.920483946800231934e-01 1.322932094335556030e-01 -1.680658757686614990e-01 -2.810868918895721436e-01 -1.739274859428405762e-01 -6.817381829023361206e-02 1.097021810710430145e-02 -3.780493140220642090e-01 1.022090688347816467e-01 -3.455026149749755859e-01 -5.340179894119501114e-03 -1.941403299570083618e-01 2.195733934640884399e-01 1.599482595920562744e-01 -6.429063156247138977e-03 -1.994361579418182373e-01 7.429709285497665405e-02 -6.186648830771446228e-02 3.215630054473876953e-01 -3.681885451078414917e-02 -2.468834519386291504e-01 5.535753443837165833e-02 -1.222386434674263000e-01 -1.336591690778732300e-01 1.399028897285461426e-01 -1.366180181503295898e-01 1.522678881883621216e-01 1.511430181562900543e-02 2.401746958494186401e-01 2.649781107902526855e-01 -5.454543828964233398e-01 -1.092205718159675598e-01 -9.328306466341018677e-02 -3.384732306003570557e-01 -1.642127931118011475e-01 2.024921774864196777e-01 -3.152533620595932007e-02 2.340486049652099609e-01 8.750239759683609009e-02 -2.784305810928344727e-01 8.590795099735260010e-02 -1.133114993572235107e-01 -3.966497257351875305e-02 -3.721207976341247559e-01 9.668816626071929932e-02 -1.251616477966308594e-01 3.858697135001420975e-03 -2.339877784252166748e-01 5.868237018585205078e-01 4.996139090508222580e-03 1.808173656463623047e-01 3.835939243435859680e-02 -8.150214701890945435e-02 -1.084734220057725906e-02 -3.009911999106407166e-02 1.546976119279861450e-01 -9.382786601781845093e-02 2.376294881105422974e-01 6.217407062649726868e-03 -1.371953040361404419e-01 -2.346184253692626953e-01 3.121209144592285156e-01 3.882350400090217590e-02 -4.442759752273559570e-01 9.198225289583206177e-02 -1.463707238435745239e-01 -1.381492167711257935e-01 1.165479123592376709e-01 -3.256337344646453857e-01 -6.764362007379531860e-02 6.391936540603637695e-02 2.433998733758926392e-01 2.343472838401794434e-01 -1.262559294700622559e-01 8.547146618366241455e-02 -2.869825363159179688e-01 -5.394507665187120438e-03 -1.538014262914657593e-01 9.915013611316680908e-02 -6.313066929578781128e-02 2.360366135835647583e-01
```

I searched a lot and some people suggest that the Word2vec text files should have a first line containing the number of words and dimensions. I tried to add those to the file but it didn't work either:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-9d20447a9587>", line 1, in <module>
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('syn0_ngram_1900_1909_full_Copy.txt' , binary = False)

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1547, in load_word2vec_format
    return _load_word2vec_format(

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py", line 288, in _load_word2vec_format
    _word2vec_read_text(fin, result, counts, vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, encoding)

  File "C:\Users\PSU\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py", line 220, in _word2vec_read_text
    raise ValueError("invalid vector on line %s (is this really the text format?)" % line_no)

ValueError: invalid vector on line 0 (is this really the text format?)
```

Finally, for the last line of error (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.552761644124984741e-01'), I believe there should be some issues with the file containing decimal values and not integers. I don't know how to change the default data type to float.

I haven't had a chance to investigate the issues with R much, but I get "object X not found" error when I run this code:

```
df <- read.wordvectors('syn0_ngram_1900_1909_full', type = 'txt', normalize = FALSE)
```

I've checked and I'm sure there's no issue with the directory or spelling.

Comment: `syn0_ngram_1900_1909_full.txt` is somewhat of an odd file-name for a full-set of word-vectors. What was the source of this file, and what documentation suggests it's in the right format for `.load_word2vec_format()`? Can you add some detail as to what its first 5 lines look like (before you tried to patch it up) to your question text?

Comment: I received the models from another researcher that had trained the models and used them in his own paper. I did some research online and found out it's pretty common to use this command to load Word2vec text files (I've mostly worked with Gensim model files and this is quite new to me as well), but I know they've used Gensim to train the models. They've used CSV outputs for their analysis in R which is another uncommon format for these models. Sure. I added the first 3 lines. Since it has 300 dimensions 5 lines didn't fit in here.

Comment: The other researcher, if providing data, should provide clear documentation about the format they've provided & how to use it. (For example, when open projects make files available for free download, they clearly describe their formats & often provide example code for how to use.) That you are getting this error strongly suggests the format is not what you think it is and that a "common" way to load other files won't be appropriate.  5 lines would fit into your question, which you may always edit/extend, easily – and there's little chance of guessing the file's format without such a sample!

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask them about it!

Comment: Thanks for the example lines! The fact that no words appear on those lines – only numbers – indicates the file is *not* any common word-vector format. (Both the text && binary formats of the original Google `word2vec.c` tool preceded each line with a word-token. So too does the format used by GLoVe. So at the very least, such a file would need some other auxiliary file to explain which rows are which words - and even with that, it'd still need more massaging to be put in a format compatible with Gensim. (Does such a word-to-row vocabulary file exist in the same data handoff?)

Comment: Yes, I figured that's the main issue. They've shared the vocabulary lists with me in separate files. I assume I need to attach the vocab list as row names to the vectors and proceed from there. Based on their response, the order of the two files (vectors and words) is the same. So, merging should be straightforward.

Comment: Indeed - if the extra file is a word-to-a-line, it may be as simple as using the `paste` command, if available on your system, as in <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-merge-two-files-line-by-line-in-bash> – though adding the `-d ' '` option to use a space instead of a tab as the delimiter. Then, your format might be conformant with the more-common 'GLoVe' format – which lacks a declarative header, but can still be read by Gensim's `glove2word2vec` utility: <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html>.

Comment: (Starting the Gensim 4.0, `load_word2vec_format` will have a new optional parameter, `no_header=True` <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html?highlight=load_word2vec_format#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format>, which allows it to read GLoVe-style files without the `glove2word2vec` extra step. However, as this requires a pre-scan of the file to count the entries, after loading such a file once, it still makes sense to re-save as the format with the pre-declared length, for faster future loads.)