# How do I copy lines next to line of another file in Linux?

Tags: linux

let's say I have two files:

file1:

```
cat dog
fox bat
rat pig
```

file2:

```
frog
deer
mouse
```

How can I get file3?

```
cat dog frog
fox bat deer
rat pig mouse
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two files line by line in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-merge-two-files-line-by-line-in-bash)

Comment: It does, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux has paste command. Basic example is as follows.

paste file1 file2 > file3