# How can I merge multiple python requirements.txt files?

Tags: python, bash, pip, requirements.txt

Before running my python program, I have to install **many separated** requirements.txt. I developed a script that installs this files but it takes **too long**, and I think that **merging all** of them in one requirements.txt would **speed up** the installation. Maybe I could develop a script that does the merge but I don't know if there is another way.

- Do you know any solution that merges multiple requirements.txt in one
  file?
- Do you think it would improve the performance?

My current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in /opt/myprogram/mymodules/*/; do
  if [ -f "$d/requirements.txt" ]; then
    echo "Installing $d requirements"
    pip install -r "$d""requirements.txt" --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed
  else
    echo "WARNING! $d has no requirements"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two files line by line in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-merge-two-files-line-by-line-in-bash)

Comment: Merging the files won't speed-up the installation much. Eliminating the duplicated entries may save a some time.

Comment: @SitiSchu I'm aware that I can do it in bash but I was looking for a python/pip solution. Thanks!

Comment: @exniagara Your example code was bash so it was unclear what you were asking, if you want to do it in python, please add your python code to the question and mention where you are stuck. (I'll have to agree with alec though, reading the files is going to be the least problem, unless your requires have lots of the same requirements.)

Comment: @SitiSchu sorry for the confussion. I know I could develop a script in any language. I meant any built-in python/pip solution to deal with multiple requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

> How can I merge multiple python requirements.txt files?

Just `cat`. `cat requirements.txt otherrquitements.txt > mergedrequirements.txt`.

> Do you think it would improve the performance?

Yes.

---

You could do:

```
pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed -r <(sort -u /opt/myprogram/mymodules/*/requirements.txt)
```

Comment: My advice is to remove duplicates: `cat requirements.txt otherrquitements.txt | sort -u > mergedrequirements.txt`

Comment: The cat solution work only when there is a newline at the end of each file, as `cat requirements.txt otherrquitements.txt` doesn't add a newline between files.

Comment: So write code that will add such newline on the end of each file, the method stays the same, and fix your editor, so it adds a newline to such files.

Comment: This won't work.  requirements.txt requires unique entries, and you won't get that if one file depends on `xyz` and another depends on `xyz==1.0`.